# C++ Merging 2 sorted arrays into 1 sorted

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So I am trying so merge 2 sorted arrays into one and I get really weird numbers like an output. Here is my code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

   int* add(int first[],int second[], int sizeFirst, int sizeSecond)
   {
        int result[sizeFirst + sizeSecond];
        int indexFirst = 0,indexSecond = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < sizeFirst + sizeSecond;i++)
        {
           if(indexFirst == sizeFirst || first[indexFirst] > second[indexSecond])
           {
               result[i] = second[indexSecond];
               indexSecond++;
           }
           else
           {
                result[i] = first[indexFirst];
                indexFirst++;
           }
        }
      return result;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n];
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i ++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        int m;
        cin>>m;
        int arr2[m];
        for(int i = 0;i < m;i ++)
            cin>>arr2[i];
        int *res;
        res = add(arr,arr2,n,m);
        for(int i = 0;i < n + m;i ++)
            cout<<res[i]<<" ";
        return 0;
    }
```

Notes: It sorts it properly, so the mistake is not there. Also I need to do it as a function because I will need it later on for some other stuff.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)?

Comment: @Wintermute I would like to program it myself for practice

Comment: how in hell does this code even compile with `int result[sizeFirst + sizeSecond];` ?

Comment: @Guiroux Codeblocks mate

Comment: `int result[sizeFirst + sizeSecond];` `return result;` this is undefined behavior, and will never work properly!

Comment: @Nick Nikolov, i guess "codeblocks mate" must be a logic and coherent answer to my question, but i can't get it

Comment: the fact is, if the code i pointed out didnt worked you would have had to allocate dynamically and wouldnt have had this problem XD

Comment: @Guiroux I don't believe that the OP has any logic or coherence on track at all :-P ...

Comment: but why does his code compiles ?

Comment: @Guiroux GCC allows it

Comment: but should it be allowed considering standards ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 return result;
```

You are returning a pointer to local array, which gets destroyed immediately after - this is undefined behavior. You should either allocate it using `new` or use `std::vector` (which is preferred).

Also, `int result[sizeFirst + sizeSecond];` is not valid C++ because the standard doesn't allow variable sized arrays (but `int* result = new int[sizeFirst + sizeSecond];` is valid).